# Ajax / Php sending id from while loop on click to view record details

Tags: php, ajax, variables, post

i have a table with differente IDs on each row (obtained from a while loop), and next to each ID i have  element to view the details of this specific record. Now i understand if i want to retrieve the id, i have to send via post method in a form, but i don't want the page to refresh because i'm using bootstrap tabs, i don't want the page to go back to the first tab, therefore, i'm trying to use Ajax not to make the page refresh.
So first of all i have my first table :

[image]

I am in Medical Records Tab > Member Medical Records.
and my View item is :
 `<td style='text-align:center;'> <ul class='nav nav-tabs'><form><a data-toggle='tab' id='testz' value='".$rowmed[0]."' href='#viewMed'  role='button'></form><i style='color: gray;' class='fa fa-eye'></i></a></td></ul>`

Now i write an ajax script with the variable **recdetailsid** in DATA:

```
<script>
    $("#testz").click(function(e) {
switchVisible();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass( "selected" );
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",

        data: { 
            recdetailsid: $(this).val(), // < note use of 'this' here

        },
        success: function(result) {
            alert('Viewing Details !');
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

`

and then to get this ajax element :

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )  {
if(isset($_POST['recdetailsid'])){
$recdetailsid=$_POST['recdetailsid'];  





$sqlmedr = "Select Record_id,Medical_Condition,Date,Notes FROM medicalrecords,teachers WHERE Teacher_id=".$comid." and medicalrecords.CommonID=teachers.CommonID  and Dependant_id IS NULL and Record_id=".$recdetailsid." ";

// Created 2 same queries with different names because can't fetch_array twice on the same query and need to pull data twice, 1 outside the while and 1 in a while for table results

$sqlmedrx = "Select Record_id,Medical_Condition,Date,Notes FROM medicalrecords,teachers WHERE Teacher_id=".$comid." and medicalrecords.CommonID=teachers.CommonID  and Dependant_id IS NULL and Record_id=".$recdetailsid." ";
// Record_id need to be sent on view click !!!!!!!!!!!! now it is specified explicitely
$resultmedr = $conn->query($sqlmedr);
$resultmedrx = $conn->query($sqlmedrx);

?>
<div  class="jumbotron" style="margin-top: 20px; padding-left:0px !important;">
    <h3 style="color:black;">Member Record</h3></div>
<?php 
$rowmedrx = mysqli_fetch_array($resultmedrx);

if ($type=='teachers') {

  echo "Record Id: <td>".$rowmedrx['Record_id']."</td> ";

echo "<table  class='table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed' width='100%' cellspacing='0'>
<thead>
    <tr bgcolor='#d3d3d3'>
        <th>Condition</th>       
        <th>Date Of Diagnosis</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>";

while ($rowmedr = mysqli_fetch_array($resultmedr)) {

    echo "<tr>
            <td>".$rowmedr['Medical_Condition']."</td>          
            <td>".$rowmedr['Date']."</td>                              
        </tr>"; 




}



echo "<tfoot>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tfoot>
</table>";
echo "Notes :  <td>".$rowmedrx['Notes']."</td> ";
 } else {

  $sqlmedr = "Select DISTINCT Record_id,Medical_Condition,Date FROM medicalrecords,teachers,dependants WHERE medicalrecords.Dependant_id=".$comid." and medicalrecords.Dependant_id=dependants.Dependant_id "; 
$resultmedr = $conn->query($sqlmedr);

echo "<table  class='table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed' width='100%' cellspacing='0'>
<thead>
    <tr bgcolor='#d3d3d3'>
        <th>Condition</th>       
        <th>Date Of Diagnosis</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>";

while ($rowmedr = mysqli_fetch_array($resultmedr)) {

    echo "<tr>
            <td>".$rowmedr['Medical_Condition']."</td>          
            <td>".$rowmedr['Date']."</td>                              
        </tr>"; 




}

echo "<tfoot>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tfoot>
</table>";

}


} } 


?>



    <div  class="jumbotron" style="margin-top: 20px; padding-left:0px !important; ">
    <h3 style="color:black;">Documents</h3></div>
```

But everything in the server $_POST brackets and isset $_POST brackets does not show, only the alert shows with the Document jumbotron.
( you can see i'm using the variable inside the query, `Record_id=".$recdetailsid."` ) , this is my whole purpose !
[image]

Can anyone give me some tips or help please ? i'm new to ajax but trying my best to get through this, appreciated!

Comment: what is $comid and $type , where is it set ?

Comment: Hello @gvmani, these are sent in the url and being retrieved correctly on top of the page through :  $comid = $_GET['id'];   and  if (strpos($url,'teachers') !== false) {
    $type="teachers";
} and are the user id + his type, here what i'm showing is his medical profile